# Is it possible to display the list of a dropdownlist programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Each ListViewItem has several dropdownlist and textboxes. All the textboxes have their **Autopostback** property set to **true**. When the page post-backs due a dropdownlist, I want the the next dropdownlist to have the focus next time when the page loads.

Not only I want the next dropdownlist to have the focus, but also to have its list deployed. Is that feasible to programmatically deploy the list?

Comment: @codingbiz, what I means is instead of clicking the drowndownlist to see the complete list, you get the effect without clicking. Sorry, I don't know the correct term for that event.

Comment: so, what do you want  the user to see if not the list? and if you don't see the list on click, when do you want the user to see it's options? on *Over* instead of *Click*?

Comment: @balexandre, when a page loads, a dropdownlist displays only 1 item. Only when you click the arrow on the left then the dropdownlist displays all the items. What I want is to get the dropdownlist display all the items without having the user to click the arrow. Getting the focus should be enough for the dropdownlist to display all the items.

Comment: what you're looking for then, is a `ListBox` not a `DropDownList`... answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're after is something that we call **Cascading DropDown** isn't that correct?

and if you're using ASP.NET, I would suggest that you try the [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/) and specially take a look at [**CascadingDropDown**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx).

---

From your comments

> ...a dropdownlist displays only 1 item. Only when you click the arrow on the left then the dropdownlist displays all the items. What I want is to get the dropdownlist display all the items without having the user to click the arrow.

This is not a DropDownList, it's only a List and in ASP.NET, the control is called [**ListBox**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx):

```
  <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
       Rows="6"
       Width="100px"
       SelectionMode="Single" 
       runat="server">

     <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:ListBox>
```

or simply:

```
  <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
       Rows="6"
       Width="100px"
       SelectionMode="Single" 
       runat="server" />
```

and

```
ListBox1.DataSource = myList;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I just looked at CascadingDropdown. All it does is to transfer focus to the next dropdownlist control (which is part of what I'm trying to accomplish), but it doesn't deploy the list. Is it possible to programmatically deploy the list?

Comment: First of all, what in the world is **deploy the list**? That controls loads the data from the code behind every time you change one dropdown, and you can focus what you want (as that's javascript)...

Comment: I know what the listbox is. The only thing I wanted to know is whether is possible to get the dropdownlist displays all the item when it gets the focus (maybe through javascript).

Comment: go to the web... find an example, and let us know ... you're making no sense at all... In HTML, you can only have this: http://jsbin.com/ucohax/1/